# .htaccess issue in Wordpress giving 404 on all pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I have a wordpress multi-site:

site1.local.loc [with subdomains on my local] and I would like to have three pages on this.

site1.local.loc/works - (posts page, but I want 'Works' as my title)

site1.local.loc/about - (static page)

site1.local.loc/contact - (static page)

Since 'Works' is my posts page where I keep putting in content, I changed my permalinks for this site to:

/works/%postname%/

However, when clicking on 'view post' at the end of posting anything, it leads me to a '404' page which means there is a disconnect. This is also the case for viewing any page. Is my .htaccess file faulty?

How do I solve this? Also how do I make all my posts appear in my 'Works' page (as in, how to make that page the posts page?)

Thanks!

**Updated: I've found out that I get a 404 for any page that I create for a site in a wordpress network.**

Comment: can you put .htaccess content here?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress

Comment: Here's another development: I switched the permalinks to their default and I got to see the individual post page. However, still getting a 'Not Found 404' error on other pages. I think the pages exist because I assigned a static page to be my home page and it appeared. The other static page is still showing a '404'.

Answer (score 0):

Create a category called "Works" that would then show all posts added to that category by simply going to /works/ all posts would then be shown as /works/post-name/.

You will need to change the permalink structure to /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: This did not work. The posts are not being displayed and I still can't see the other pages. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post to fix the permalink structure. Maybe try that?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to touch .htaccess file.

Make a custom post type that is called works. All those posts made in that custom post type will have that url that you desire. There is no other way to do it. (even if there is, it must be dirty) That is celanest way, and since wp does it by itself you can expect that nothing will go wrong wnen you update, install plugins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check this in administration

> Settings > Permalinks > Post name